# div displayed by hover and still displayed

Tags: jquery, mouseevent, mouseover, jquery-hover, onhover

I need help in "jquery" code that do that:
First we can tell I have two div's (div 1)'visible' and (div 2)'hidden' , I want to make hover on (div 1) make (div 2)'visible'.then:
Second when I move with mouse to (div 2) disappered , I want (div 2)and(div 1) be visible till I stay in any one of them

Make two div's are visible if I stay on one of them

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, please see the [ask] help page and perhaps re-read the [tour].  SO is here to help you with specific problems you have in the code you've tried.  See also [how much effort is required to ask](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).   In this case, we'd expect to see your HTML with relevant css, so we can see how it's laid out and your attempt in javascript - don't worry if the attempt doesn't work, that's what you're asking.

Comment: TBH your requirement is a little unclear.  When mouse is over d1, show d2 - ok.  When move to d2, *something* disappears - d2?  so when you move *out* of d1? or only when you move in d2, d2 then disappears? Or d1 disappears?   These are then both contradicted by "d1 + d2 be visible *until* you *stay* in either - so if you "stay" in a div, it then hides?

Comment: @freedomn-m    if mouse on link-1 div-1 appear then move to div-1 to hover on other link such as link-2 div-2 appear the problem now if I go by mouse to div-2 , div-1 disappear.

Comment: *now if I go by mouse to div-2 , div-1 disappear.* - please be clear:  "div-1 disappears *and should not*" or "div-1 *should* disappear *but does not*.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to say that you have two `div` say `div1` and `div2`(initially hidden), when `div1` is hovered,`div2` is visible and it is visible also when hovered on `div2` and disappears when mouse leaves.
**Here is the solution you are looking for!**

HTML:

```
<div class="div1">Div-1</div>
<div class="div2">Div-2</div>
```

CSS:

```
.div2 {
  display: none;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {}
    $(".div1").mouseenter(function() {
      $(".div2").show();
    });
    $(".div2").mouseleave(function() {
      $(".div2").hide();
    });
    $(".div2").mouseenter(function() {
      $(".div2").show();
    });
  });
```